# Berry Phase in Graphene

Tags: resource-recommendations, graphene, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am trying to understand the a) Concept of Berry Phase b) its effects/ observation in graphene. I am an experimental physicist and I want to understand these concepts without getting awed by mathematics. Can anyone point me to good resources for these topics?